# how to load country state district from json webserver to javascript dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, webserver

my webserver link: https://pay.ijhs.in/dbrix/WRequest?RequestType=GAR

**return JSON data from my webserver look like:**

```
   {
     "C_Country":[{"C_Country_ID":1,"Name":"countryname"},
                  {"C_Country_ID":2,"Name":"countryname"},
                 ],
"C_Region":[{"C_Region_ID":1,"C_Country_ID":1,"Name":"statename"},
                  {"C_Region_ID":2,"C_Country_ID":1,"Name":"statename"},
                  {"C_Region_ID":3,"C_Country_ID":2,"Name":"statename"},
                  {"C_Region_ID":4,"C_Country_ID":2,"Name":"statename"},
                 ],
    "C_City":[{"C_Region_ID":1,"C_City_ID":1,"Name":"statename"},
                  {"C_Region_ID":2,"C_City":1,"Name":"statename"},
                  {"C_Region_ID":3,"C_City":2,"Name":"statename"},
                  {"C_Region_ID":4,"C_City":2,"Name":"statename"},
                 ],
    
    }
```

Comment: Which result do you expect, an array with all districts to put in the dropdown?

Comment: no......i have to fetch the country state city in  3 select box according to the country  id i select